# Compare input from Excel and write to .txt file

Tags: python, excel

I have an input in Excel like this:

```
Column1 Column2
1       test1
1       test2
2       test3
2       test4
2       test5
```

My goal is to compare the column1 numbers and if they are equal then join column2 string to list with space between and write the list to .txt file.
Basically the result should be in the .txt file like this:

```
test1 test2
test3 test4 test5
```

**I need help with the last part, writing to the new list or file where strings are joind and separated with space. If the number changes(like from 1 to 2) then the new string should be on the new line in the file/list**

At the moment if have this much:

```
import xlrd
from os import sys

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

col1 = []
col2 = []
out = []
col1.append(worksheet.col_values(0))
col2.append(worksheet.col_values(1))
n = 0
m = 1
for n in range(len(col1)):
    for m in range(len(col1)):
        if col1[n] == col1[m]:
            out.append(col2[n])
    m += 1
n += 1
print '%s' % out
```

Comment: You can do this in access using a cross tab query. You don't need a python unless you are looking to batch multiple excel files. You might have to add a third column but I think it could be done.

Comment: I just wanted to do it in python, do get to know it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to get all items with same int values. And finally print the list items as a string in your text file. I am posting the code for your last part that needs to change.

```
from collections import defaultdict
res_dict = defaultdict(list)

for n in range(len(col1)):
  res_dict[col1[n]].append(col2[n])

for key, val_list in res_dict.items():
  text_file_handle.write(' '.join(val_list) + '\n')
```

Comment: It gives me an error:   
res_dict[col1[n]].append(col2[n])   
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'  
  
convert list to dictionary?

Comment: what is `col1[n]`. Can you print that in for loop and post here.

Comment: for n in range(len(col1)):  
  print '%s' % col1[n]  
gives out:  [1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]